# Using DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a WP8 game with overlaying XMAL for the interface. I will be using multiple buttons. When the button is clicked, it will do something, and then "cooldown".

The cool down lasts for about 4 seconds and in that 4 seconds the button is not enabled. Every second the *counter* on the button will go down. Once it gets to 0 it will be enabled again.

I'm not sure how to update the buttons text per second to show the cooldown time. I was thinking of implementing the below

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();


private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // code goes here
}
```

Even on a PC, I don't think it would be a good idea to do this for something that could have up to nine buttons, so I definitely don't want to do it on a mobile device.

I'm fairly certain I can go around this using databinding but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: How else would you do it? Certainly you could (and should) use data binding; but its still going to be off of a timer tick. It fires every second; that is **forever** in CPU time. What problem do you anticipate? Do you just need help with the binding?

Comment: A DispatcherTimer or as many of them as there are buttons is OK if you keep your main thread free from long running tasks. Keep in mind that the _Tick call will wait for the main thread to get free and if it gets busy for more than 0.1 seconds it will be noticeable as non-smooth countdown on your buttons.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm kinda noobie when it comes to the threading stuff. I just didn't want to do something that would cause phones to melt in hands (not literally).